# HotTowel EF6 MVC5 Angular Breeze version challenge

Tags: entity-framework, breeze, asp.net-mvc-5, entity-framework-6, hottowel

Is it Possible to Get HotTowel and EntityFramework 6 working together?

Our DataAccess Layer was upgraded to EF6. 
The only reference we have to EntityFramework in the Web layer is the Web.Config

```
 <section name="entityFramework" type="System.Data.Entity.Internal.ConfigFile.EntityFrameworkSection, EntityFramework, Version=5.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false" />

 <entityFramework>
   <defaultConnectionFactory type="System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.SqlConnectionFactory, EntityFramework">
  <parameters>
      <parameter value="Data Source=.; Integrated Security=True; MultipleActiveResultSets=True" />
      </parameters>
   </defaultConnectionFactory>
</entityFramework>
```

We are unable to update the ER version 6 because HotTowel 
There was a Breeze Update available. But how to resolve the HotTowel

Install failed. Rolling back...
install-package : Updating 'Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.OData 5.0.0' to 'Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.OData 4.0.30506' failed. Unable to find a version of 'Breeze.Server.WebApi2' that is compatible with 
'Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.OData 4.0.30506'.

EDIT:
**We are using KNOCKOUT.js library version of HotTowel.**

Comment: HotTowel can refer to two versions of the template - One for Knockout.js and one for Angular.js.  It would be helpful to include which you are working with.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There was an incompat that the Web APi v2 had when it came out (same week as my course). It is now resolved so just install

```
Install-Package HotTowel.Angular.Breeze -pre
```

Comment: Big fan of your talks sir.. and SPAs.

Comment: The man himself... Im getting further, so i'll pay that.  Now have new issues.... Seems MVC5 isnt playing properly.

Comment: A made a detail answer since johns suggestion was a good start, but not the full solution for me. So in case you are HERE check the detail answer i added

Comment: FYI - the release version of HotTowel is now available so you can now do install-package `HotTowel.Angular.Breeze` without the -pre option

Answer (score 4):

The QUICK version of John Papas answer
YES i needed the pre version of HOtTowel, actual more the angularJS Pre version.
But that didnt resolve all issues.
I needed breeze packages for ef6 and also the WEB.CONFIG entries.

> Install-Package HotTowel.Angular.Breeze -pre

ALSO I had to use
**Install-Package Breeze.WebApi2.EF6**

See their site for more info WHY
[Breeze and EF6](http://www.breezejs.com/documentation/start-nuget)

A detail Explanation for what helped get it running.   About 12 hrs later... Just in case someone has the issue:
I would describe it as ef6, MVC5, Razor, Hottowel, AngularJs Breeze Knockout combo
**The package COMBINATION**

```
<packages>
  <package id="AngularJS.Animate" version="1.2.0-rc3" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="AngularJS.Core" version="1.2.0-rc3" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="AngularJS.Route" version="1.2.0-rc3" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="AngularJS.Sanitize" version="1.2.0-rc3" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Antlr" version="3.5.0.2" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Breeze.Client" version="1.4.5" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Breeze.Server.ContextProvider" version="1.4.5" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Breeze.Server.ContextProvider.EF6" version="1.4.5" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Breeze.Server.WebApi2" version="1.4.5" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Breeze.WebApi2.EF6" version="1.4.5" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Durandal" version="2.0.1" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Durandal.Router" version="1.2.0" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Durandal.Transitions" version="2.0.0" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="EntityFramework" version="6.0.1" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="FontAwesome" version="4.0.0" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="HotTowel.Angular" version="2.0.1-rc3" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="HotTowel.Angular.Breeze" version="2.0.1-rc3" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="infuser" version="0.2.1" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="jQuery" version="2.0.3" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="jQuery.Form" version="3.32" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="jQuery.UI.Combined" version="1.10.3" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="jQuery.Validation" version="1.11.1" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Knockout.js_External_Template_Engine" version="2.0.5" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Knockout.Mapping" version="2.4.0" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Knockout.Validation" version="1.0.1" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="knockoutjs" version="2.3.0" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc" version="5.0.0" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc.FixedDisplayModes" version="5.0.0" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.Razor" version="3.0.0" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.Web.Optimization" version="1.1.2" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi" version="5.0.0" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Client" version="5.0.0" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Core" version="5.0.0" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.OData" version="5.0.0" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Tracing" version="5.0.0" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.WebHost" version="5.0.0" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.WebPages" version="3.0.0" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Data.Edm" version="5.6.0" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Data.OData" version="5.6.0" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Web.Infrastructure" version="1.0.0.0" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Modernizr" version="2.6.2" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Moment.js" version="2.1.0" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Newtonsoft.Json" version="5.0.8" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Q" version="0.9.7" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="RequireJS" version="2.1.8" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="RequireJS.Text" version="2.0.7" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Sammy.js" version="0.7.4" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Spin.js" version="1.3" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="System.Spatial" version="5.6.0" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="TinyMCE.JQuery" version="4.0.8" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="toastr" version="2.0.1" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="TrafficCop" version="0.3.1" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Twitter.Bootstrap" version="2.3.2" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Unity" version="3.0.1304.0" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="WebActivator" version="1.5.3" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="WebActivatorEx" version="2.0.2" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="WebGrease" version="1.5.2" targetFramework="net45" />
</packages>
```

**AND SOME VERY IMPORT WEB.CONFIG entries
Under Views/**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <sectionGroup name="system.web.webPages.razor" type="System.Web.WebPages.Razor.Configuration.RazorWebSectionGroup, System.Web.WebPages.Razor, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35">
      <section name="host" type="System.Web.WebPages.Razor.Configuration.HostSection, System.Web.WebPages.Razor, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" requirePermission="false" />
      <section name="pages" type="System.Web.WebPages.Razor.Configuration.RazorPagesSection, System.Web.WebPages.Razor, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" requirePermission="false" />
</sectionGroup>
  </configSections>

  <system.web.webPages.razor>
    <host factoryType="System.Web.Mvc.MvcWebRazorHostFactory, System.Web.Mvc, Version=5.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
    <pages pageBaseType="System.Web.Mvc.WebViewPage">
      <namespaces>
    <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc" />
    <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Ajax" />
    <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Html" />
    <add namespace="System.Web.Optimization"/>
    <add namespace="System.Web.Routing" />
  </namespaces>
    </pages>
  </system.web.webPages.razor>

  <appSettings>
  <add key="webpages:Enabled" value="false" />
  </appSettings>

 <system.web>
  <httpHandlers>
    <add path="*" verb="*" type="System.Web.HttpNotFoundHandler"/>
  </httpHandlers>
  <pages
    validateRequest="false"
    pageParserFilterType="System.Web.Mvc.ViewTypeParserFilter, System.Web.Mvc, Version=5.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"
    pageBaseType="System.Web.Mvc.ViewPage, System.Web.Mvc, Version=5.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"
    userControlBaseType="System.Web.Mvc.ViewUserControl, System.Web.Mvc, Version=5.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35">
   <controls>
    <add assembly="System.Web.Mvc, Version=5.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" namespace="System.Web.Mvc" tagPrefix="mvc" />
   </controls>
 </pages>
</system.web>

 <system.webServer>
  <validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false" />

 <handlers>
  <remove name="BlockViewHandler"/>
  <add name="BlockViewHandler" path="*" verb="*" preCondition="integratedMode" type="System.Web.HttpNotFoundHandler" />
 </handlers>
 </system.webServer>
 </configuration>
```

> Then in ROOT Web.Config, check these entries are OK regarding
>   versions

```
<add key="webpages:Version" value="3.0.0" />
<add key="webpages:Enabled" value="false" />
<add key="PreserveLoginUrl" value="true" />
<add key="ClientValidationEnabled" value="true" />
<add key="UnobtrusiveJavaScriptEnabled" value="true" />
```

**no change should be required Namespaces, but just in case.**

```
 <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5" />
   <pages>
    <namespaces>
    <add namespace="System.Web.Helpers" />
    <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc" />
    <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Ajax" />
    <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Html" />
    <add namespace="System.Web.Optimization" />
    <add namespace="System.Web.Routing" />
    <add namespace="System.Web.WebPages" />
   </namespaces>
  </pages>
```

**and some dependent assembly tweaks to versions**

```
<runtime>
<assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
  <dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.WebPages.Razor" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-3.0.0.0" newVersion="3.0.0.0" />
  </dependentAssembly>

  <dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Helpers" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-2.0.0.0" newVersion="3.0.0.0" />
  </dependentAssembly>
  <dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Mvc" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-5.0.0.0" newVersion="5.0.0.0" />
  </dependentAssembly>
  <dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.WebPages" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-3.0.0.0" newVersion="3.0.0.0" />
  </dependentAssembly>
  <dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="WebGrease" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-1.5.2.14234" newVersion="1.5.2.14234" />
  </dependentAssembly>
  <dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="Antlr3.Runtime" publicKeyToken="eb42632606e9261f" culture="neutral" />
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-3.5.0.2" newVersion="3.5.0.2" />
  </dependentAssembly>
</assemblyBinding>
```